# "Change Bluetooth Connectivity" Permission in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-permissions

I'm currently having problem with Bluetooth permission in my Apps.

Basically I want to turn on the "Change Bluetooth connectivity" permission when user install the apps.

[This is the permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldLNJ.png)

Here is my Manifest Permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
```

Here is my code:

```
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

When I Install the Samsung Gear, that particular permission is turned on before I open the apps, so there must be a ways to turn it on.

[Samsung Gear Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46b69.png)

Thank you for the help guys!

Comment: [Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Have added Permissions at Run Time, still not working